# Пробел нулевой ширины

Tags: c#

Есть у меня программа - Генератор паролей.
Узнал, что в пароли добавляют, так называемый: **Пробел нулевой ширины**

U+200B

Другие символы в генераторе паролей я добавляю так:

```
                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    chars += "0123456789";
                }
                if (checkBox2.Checked)
                {
                    chars += "!@#$%^&*()";
                }
```

В итоге решил по такому же принципу добавить этот символ:

```
                if (zerowidth_checkBox.Checked)
                {
                    chars += '\u200B';
                }
```

Собственно вопрос: правильно ли я делаю? И как можно проверть наличие данного символа.

Comment: `chars.Contains(ваш символ)`?

Comment: Итоговый пароль будет вводиться пользователем вручную? Если да, то как он будет вводить такой символ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov чекбокс отметит?

Comment: Я не пойму зачем такая сложность. Если пин-код на карте 4 числа. Делайте пароль чтоб пользователь мог ввести, а не взломать. :)

Comment: @AzizUmarov эпоха паролей подходит к концу, да. Например, в Телегаме вообще нет пароля, и многие сервисы уже переходят на такую авторизацию. А еще есть OpenID, OAuth, и тд.. Смысла делать свой велосипед с паролями примерно никакого.

Comment: @aepot причем тут OpenID, OAuth, и тд? У меня десктопное приложение, а не сервис. Мы говорим с вами о совсем разных вещах. Те же криптоконтейнеры использут именно пароль, а не сторонние левые сервисы. Ваш пароль должен находиться только у вас в голове, а не передаваться какой-то третьей стороне.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо), попробую.